# Json property alias in typescript

Tags: json, typescript

Let's say I want to get a data from `Visual Studio TFS` and the response (as json) is in this kind of format:

```
{
    "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints": 3.0,
    // ......
}
```

There's dot in the property name. Reading from other questions I found out that I can read that json in typescript by using an interface like this

```
export interface IStory { // I don't think this kind of interface do me any help
    "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints": number
}
```

And then I can use the property with this syntax:

```
var story = GetStoryFromTFS();
console.log(story["Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints"]);
```

But I'd prefer not to call the property like this, since the intellisense won't able to help me finding which property I want to use (because I call the property using a string).

In C# there is a `JsonProperty` attribute which enable me to create a model like this:

```
public class Story
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints")]
    public double StoryPoints { get; set; }
}
```

And then I can use the property this way:

```
var story = GetStoryFromTFS();
Console.WriteLine(story.StoryPoints);
```

This way the intellisense will able to help me finding which property I want to use.

Is there something like `JsonProperty` attribute in typescript? Or is there any other, better way, to achieve this in typescript?

Comment: there is no way to create aliases, you can make a class that decorates the server data with getters and setters but that's a lot of code to write for some server data. Easier would be to just use simpler names for your json properties

Comment: @toskv if there is a rule that I shouldn't change the json data's property name which is retrieved from the api, there's no work around in typescript then?

Comment: you can only do what you can do in js, and that's either wrap it in something else, or just copy it to another object that has properties you like.. if the names of the properties are set in stone you don't have much choice..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have many options. Just keep in mind that all of these options require you to pass the original data to the class that will access it.

Map the values.

```
class StoryMap {
    constructor(data: IStory) {
        this.StoryPoints = data["Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints"];
     }

    StoryPoints: number;
}
```

Wrap the data.

```
class StoryWrap {
    constructor(private data: IStory) {}

    get StoryPoints(): number { return this.data["Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints"] };
}
```

Build a decorator to map the data.

```
function JsonProperty(name: string) {
    return function DoJsonProperty(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        descriptor.get = function () {
            return this.data[name];
        }
        descriptor.set = function (value) {
            this.data[name] = value;
        }
    }
}

class StoryDecorator
{
    constructor(private data: IStory) {}

    @JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints")
    get StoryPoints(): number { return 0 };

}
```

Comment: In your code you are referencing `this` from within the `descriptor` making `this` the `descriptor` not the `target`. Wouldn't it make sense to instead use `target.data`? I was receiving type errors for the previous solution.