# JsonProperty in Angular TypeScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I have a Asp.Net MVC 5 ApiController for CRUD operations.
I use an Angular client to consume this service. The data uses JsonProperty due to the fact that I want to reduce the amount of data transferred (for other uses).

```
 class TestClass {
    [JsonProperty("N")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("A")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("I")]
    public string InformationType { get; set; }
}
```

My current solution in Angular is to provide a model class which fits the Json like this:

```
    export interface ITestClass {
        N: string,
        A: string,
        I: string,
    }
...//example get
    get(url: string): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(url)
            .map((response: Response) => <ITestClass>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

This works so far (also for Post / Put) operations.
But would prefer to have such a JsonProperty on the client to, so that I can work with a class that uses "correct" names.
Is there a simple way in Angular to achieve this?

Comment: that is not possible in Typescript

Comment: `get(url: string):  Observable< ITestClass> `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json property alias in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075826/json-property-alias-in-typescript)